# How can I move the vim cursor with the mouse wheel in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, vim, iterm2

This currently works as I want it to in the regular Mac Terminal, but not in iTerm2. Currently, using the mouse wheel shows my terminal and moves vim down.

To be clear, I don’t want to scroll the whole page up and down, just want the cursor itself to move.

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands:

```
set mouse=a
map <ScrollWheelDown> j
map <ScrollWheelUp> k
```

The first line enables the scroll wheel in all modes, but you can consider using `set mouse=n` instead to only scroll in Normal mode.

The next two lines map vertical scroll wheel motions to vertical cursor motions.  You can do the same thing with horizontal scrolling (using `h` and `l`), but it depends on your system and can take some more work; see `:help scroll-mouse-wheel`

Answer (score 1):

[image]I come looking for this every time i upgrade my mac.
but going to iterm -> preferences -> profiles -> terminal -> and clicking enable mouse reporting

Allows `:set mouse=a` to work.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493548/167408